# How can i get item custom option from shipment item

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1

How can i get item custom option from shipment item

my code is as

I am tring to get this using `$options = $item->getProductOptions();` but it gives blank.

```
    <?php $_order = $this->getOrder() ?>
<?php $group = $this->getGroupcode(); ?>
<?php $shipmentId = $this->getShipmentid(); ?>
<?php if ($_order): ?>
<?php foreach($_order->getShipmentsCollection() as $shipment): ?>
    <?php foreach($shipment->getItemsCollection() as $item): ?>
        <?php
        $options = $item->getProductOptions();
        echo "<pre/>";print_r($item->getData());exit;
        $lineId = $options['info_buyRequest']['additional_options']['productline_id'];
        $groupId = Mage::getModel('productline/productline')->load($lineId)->getShippinggroup();
        if(!empty($options['info_buyRequest']['additional_options']['item_shippinggroup'])){
            $itemGroup = $options['info_buyRequest']['additional_options']['item_shippinggroup'];
        }else{
            $itemGroup =  trim(Mage::getModel('shippinggroup/shippinggroup')->load($groupId)->getTitle());
        }
        ?>
        <?php if($group == $itemGroup && $shipmentId == $shipment->getIncrementId()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get order item detail only in order item table, not in shipment item table. You can try this to get item detail :

```
<?php $_order = $this->getOrder() ?>
<?php $group = $this->getGroupcode(); ?>
<?php $shipmentId = $this->getShipmentid(); ?>
<?php if ($_order): ?>
<?php foreach($_order->getShipmentsCollection() as $shipment): ?>
    <?php foreach($shipment->getItemsCollection() as $item): ?>
    <?php
    $options = $item->getProductOptions();
    $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load($item->getOrderItemId());
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($orderItem->getData());exit;
    //echo "<pre/>";print_r($item->getData());exit;
    $lineId = $options['info_buyRequest']['additional_options']['productline_id'];
    $groupId = Mage::getModel('productline/productline')->load($lineId)->getShippinggroup();
    if(!empty($options['info_buyRequest']['additional_options']['item_shippinggroup'])){
        $itemGroup = $options['info_buyRequest']['additional_options']['item_shippinggroup'];
    }else{
        $itemGroup =  trim(Mage::getModel('shippinggroup/shippinggroup')->load($groupId)->getTitle());
    }
    ?>
    <?php if($group == $itemGroup && $shipmentId == $shipment->getIncrementId()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```